# Creating a new module in Sitefinity

Tags: module, controls, command, sitefinity

I'm trying to create a new module for Sitefinity. I'm basing my module off the sample module linked to from the documentation. http://www.sitefinity.com/help/developer-manual/adding-modules-pluggable-explained.html

What I want is a list of videos. On the left-hand side - the CommandPanel - there should be 3 buttons - "Videos", "Artists" and "Genres".

Whenever either of these is selected, on the right-hand-side, a list of Videos/Artists/Genres should be displayed.

The concept is simple, but what I'm struggling with is, where to actually put the code.

Should I hard-code the list directly into CommandPanel.ascx? Am I supposed to create new controls for Videos, Artists and Genres? Or should I have one control and multiple Panels, which I show/hide? And how do I connect the menu items on the left with changing the panel on the right?

NB. I might be wrong to have Videos, Artists and Genres all on the left. Maybe it should just be "Videos", and Artists and Genres should be separate module each?

I don't need a complete answer, just some direction on how to code in this framework, and where everything should go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there I just saw this come up I am not sure if you have already started this module yet you may even be finished by now, but I just wanted to say had you checked out the Sitefinity Beta for 3.6 because they are about to simplify the whole Sitefinity module process and particularly for what you are trying to do.  Check it on the Sitefinity block a [barebones module with the new architecture](http://blogs.sitefinity.com/Ivan/Posts/09-01-25/Sitefinity_3_6_beta_-_sample_bare_bones_module_on_the_new_backend_architecture.aspx).  This I think would satisfy your needs because you can create a separate "View" for each one of your Videos, Artist and Genres and all their views like create, edit etc.